# Why LinqPad return The name 'ModelName' does not exist in the current context error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linqpad

I have a **Asp.net MVC - C#** project and want to use **LINQPad** to test some Entity Framework statements of it before use them in the project.

The project has different class libraries such as

- **DAL** (include the `ApplicationDbContext` class)
- **Domain Classes** (models)

**A)** I added an **EF Connection** to the **DAL** in *LINQPad* and it loaded all of the entities in the left tree in its window successfully. *[See the bellow image]*

[image]

**B)** Also i added the some required references from *LINQPad Query* to the following DLLs:

- DAL dll
- Domain Classes dll
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
- EntityFramework.dll

---

### But »

When i right click on an entity in the left tree and select each option, it show this error:

> The name '[Conceptual_Model_Name]' does not exist in the current context

**Why?** 
**How can i resolve this problem?**

---

**Edit 1:**

In the **`OnModelCreating`** method of `ApplicationDbContext` class i call the following method to **add entities to the `DbContext` dynamically**.

```
    public void LoadEntities(Assembly asm, DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string nameSpace)
    {
        var entityTypes = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null &&
                           type.Namespace == nameSpace &&
                           type.BaseType == null)
            .ToList();

        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
        entityTypes.ForEach(type => entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { }));
    }
```

I call it with this line of code:

```
LoadEntities(typeof(AppUser).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, modelBuilder, "DomainClasses.Entities");
```

Is it possible the reason be related to this dynamic loading of models?

Comment: To start you can switch to the latest version (5) of LinqPad

Comment: @Steve, ok i try v5 too but i appended some new info to the question (about dynamic loading the entities in the DBContext class). Have you any idea about it?

Comment: @Steve, i tested it with last version (5). The result did not change.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about this behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself !

The suspicion that i wrote about it in the question, was correct. As I wrote in the question i add the entities to the `DbContext` as *dynamically* but now i changed it to the *static way* like this:

```
// Add this property to the ApplicationDbContext class

public virtual DbSet<Consumption> Consumptions { get; set; }
```

Now when i use `Consumptions` property in `LINQPad` it works...